# remove a variable from a link that comes in a url one or many times

Tags: jquery

i wanted to remove a variable and its value from a`href` link like suppose the link has `quantity=1` one time or two times then i want to remove it no matter how many times it comes in that link. what i had in my mind is to use the jquery `replace` . i made a code .

```
   var url = i.text.replace('&quantity','');
```

where i had the value

```
"https://example.com?pid=1&quantity=2&quantity=3"
```

but if i use `replace` i wont be able to remove the value of the variable. So what to do so that not only the string `&quantity` is removed but also the value associated with it is also removed like full `&quantity=3`. also keeping in mind that `quantity` and its values are dynamic it can be one time in the link with some other value or two times with some other.

Comment: Did you try `.replaceWith()` in jquery.Cause I don't think `.replace` is jquery function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like:

```
var text = "https://example.com?pid=1&quantity=2&quantity=3";
var url = text.replace(/&quantity=\d+/g,'');
```

That'll replace the `=` sign and whatever number you have after, just make sure your variables are OK...

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/afXMN/

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined` i am getting this error when u i am using your code :(

Comment: There must be something wrong with your variables, because that works, see my jsfiddle on the edit I just did to the answer...

Comment: in my case its removing the value after the `&quantity` now

Comment: ok i got to know where is the problem . Actually i am filling the value of quantity in a text box and on keyup i am using to update the value in link. so if i use backspace to delete the previous value then `quantity=` without any value is sent. for which this code does not works . can it be possible to make it work for both `&quantity` and `&quantity=3` ?

Comment: dont worry i was able to make it via if else and i wanted it the way it worked . thanks for this hint :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $_post function rather than the get to hide this value if you wish or use a session